# Solar boost converter unstability

Tags: solar-cell, dc-dc-converter, boost, converter

My design of a boost converter is the following
Input: 40V/1.5A
Output: 100v/0.62A

Inductance used: 3.15mH

Capacitance used: 220uF (rated 200V)

diode

switch used: IRF830 (rated Vds=500v)

Switching Pulse: 5v at 50% duty cycle and 31250Hz frequency.

when I measure the voltage output after running the converter, it will first increase from 40 up to 120 at approximate time of 10 seconds then it will increase by 0.1 every time and keep getting more at a slower rate, I'm not sure what seem be the problem for the voltage to  be at 100V or at any value less than 200 because the capacitor rated 200v

Please guide me, Thanks

[image: boost converter]

Comment: Did you try adding a load or sensing?

Comment: I'm sensing the output without the load, because I will use that potential to an inverter (DC/AC) (semikron an-8005), i tried a load but the voltage dropped to 3v only.

Comment: If the voltage drops so drastically under load then your output impedance is too high.

Comment: This question is confused.  The schematic shows a NPN switch, but the text says it's a FET.  You need to fix one of them.  Also no diode spec.

Answer (score 2):

The output capacitor rating has nothing to do with what the output voltage will be.  The rating only says at what voltage the capcitor will fail.

With no load, this type of boost converter should keep increasing its output voltage theoretically forever.  In practise, of course, something will limit the voltage.  Your parts are all rated higher than the voltage you are getting, so they shouldn't be failing and loading the output voltage.  Here are some possibilities:

The switch is being turned on or off slowly.  You don't show how the switch is being driven, and you say it's a NPN in one place and imply its a FET in another, so we can't tell what is going on.

The diode is leaking back during reverse recovery.  You say nothing about the diode, so again we can't tell.  A 1N4004, for example, would be totally inappropriate here.

Comment: it is a FET not like on the photo.

Comment: the diode I'm using is 1N4007 or something similar (same family i think), why I should not be using this type ?

Comment: is it because it's slow ? 
can I use BYX71

Comment: @John: Showing one thing in the schematic but actually using something else just wastes everyone's time.  Screw this, I'm outta here.